# Is it possible to have kube-proxy without the kubernetes environment in vm pod using istio mesh expansion

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kube-proxy

I have been working on a very innovative project which involves both Kubernetes and Istio. So, I have 2-node kubernetes cluster setup with istio installed withe their side cars in the pods. I have already hosted the bookinfo application in the nodes but by using a **separate VM** by following the procedures given in **Istio Mesh-Expansion**.

So I have VM where the details and Mysqldb pods are present. The other pods are running in the k8s cluster. So Now, They communicate within a private network.

So my next phase of project would require me to **setup Kube-proxy separately without installing Kubernetes** in the VM, so as to allow it to directly communicate to the Kube-Api Server running in the master nodes of the k8s cluster through the private network. Hence, Can anybody suggest a way how to go about this?

Comment: You can probably add that node to cluster and then taint it such that no pods are scheduled on that node? This makes sure that node is Kubernetes managed, Kube proxy is running as well as allows you to run stuff you want to run?

Comment: Nope The whole project is to have kube-proxy running on a VM without kubernetes installed in the vm. We should have a independent kube-proxy which generates iptables in such a way that we can communicate to the other pods within the k8s cluster as if it was inside the k8s cluster

Answer (score 0):

All components of Kubernetes should be connected to the `kube-api`. Otherwise, they will not work.

> So my next phase of project would require me to setup Kube-proxy separately without installing Kubernetes in the VM, so as to allow it to directly communicate to the Kube-Api Server running in the master nodes of the k8s cluster through the private network.

To access the `kube-api` server using `Service` with the private `ClusterIP` address, you should already have a `kube-proxy`. So, it is impossible to use any `ClusterIP` private address until you setup `kube-proxy` which is communicating with your `kube-api` by its address outside the Cluster IP range.

`Kube-api` can be exposed using `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type of service.